# Android Sqlite Read Column Values with Previous and Next Options

Tags: android, sqlite, multiple-columns

I have a Sqlite table In that I am Selecting one row at a time with Limit 1.. like

```
cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE status in ('new') LIMIT 1", null);
```

So Now I want to read the values of all columns with previous/next options

I tried with String list but its not working

I am Using this for Voice Based application So If User Says `Next/Previous` It should Say/Display Next Value..
I have Done with Speech to text and Text to speech but I Struck at Previous Next

If I Filter Previous and Next from that row I can add voice to them

My Column Values like

```
1,Android,Oreo,4gb,64gb,2.2Ghz,4000mhz,$800,May2019.
```

I want to get these Column values one by one

I googled a lot but I got previous and next with rows.. but not column values

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following as the basis

```
    ........ existing code
    int current_column = 0;
    show_value();

}

// Called when event requires next
private next_column() {
    if (current_column < (cursor.getColumnCount() - 1) {
        current_column++;
        show_value();
    }
}
// Called when event requires prev
private prev_column() {
    if (current_column > 0 {
        current_column--;
        show_value();
    }
}

private void show_value() {
    String current_value = cursor.getString(current_column);
    your_appropriate_view.setText(current_value);
}
```